# How to enable logging option in android and ios devices using xamarin.forms app

Tags: android, ios, logging, xamarin.forms

In my cross-platform Xamarin Forms application I would like to have a Logging option. If it's enabled, it should generate a log file stating the errors or in which step the app is crashing (if any of these takes places while the app is running) and I should be able to pull and check this generated log file.

When I googled for this I found on many sites that we need to debug using usb and check it on android adb, but once the application goes live and user downloads it in their phone if app crashes any time then the user should be able to turn on the logging button and once the process is run it generates a log file. The user can then send the file to the developer to check what exactly is happening in the system.

How do I implement this feature in Xamarin Forms for both iPhone and Android?

Comment: http://appcenter.ms

Answer (score 0):

What about analytics service like hokeyapp or appcenter.ms
They do what you and more.

But if you want to implements this by yourself is still possible but you need to write specific code on both plateform to handle exception and write them on files with stack traces